# Changing the owner of Opportunity object in Salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

In after insert trigger of a opportunity's child object I have to change the owner of Opportunity if certain condition evaluates to true.

Problem here is The owner is lookup field to User Object.And I have to change the owner to a user of particular Profile.How do I access the profile and user fields in a after insert trigger of opportunity's child object.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Owner ID and Profile ID from the Oppty

```
ID ownerProfileID = Opportunity.OwnerID.getProfileId(); (This is rough, I don't know your variable names)
Map<ID, Profile> profileMap = new Map<ID, Profile>(ProfileHandler.loadProfilesByProfileIDs(new Set<ID>{ownerProfileID }));
```

Then Query and you will have all your data

```
public static Map<ID, Profile> loadProfilesByProfileIDs(Set<ID> profileIDS)
{
    Map<ID, Profile> result = new Map<ID, Profile>();

    try
    {
        result = new Map<ID, Profile>([SELECT ID, Name FROM Profile WHERE ID =: profileIDS]);
    }
    catch(QueryException error)
    {
        //Catch error
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample Query from Opportunity Product to Query Opportunity Owner Field Details:

```
   SELECT 
   Opportunity.OwnerId, 
   Opportunity.Owner.Name, 
   Opportunity.Owner.ProfileId,
   Opportunity.Owner.Profile.Name  
   FROM OpportunityLineItem 
   WHERE ID='00k6F00000TdIlH'
```